# Sending request to an AWS API Gateway that uses AWS Cognito

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, request, amazon-cognito, gateway

I've been reading the official documentation but I'm still not sure *what are the request parameters needed in the POST* to get a successful response.

I was given user-name, password, app-client-id, user-pool-id, cognito and api gateway regions, identity-pool-id, and the url for invoking the api.

Is a Signature Version 4 required in the request header? I'm using the AWS Java SDK in case the AWS4Signer is useful.

Thanks! Probably an example request is enough explanation.

Comment: What is the authorizer configuration for your API Gateway endpoint? That will determine what you POST with

Comment: hi @bwinant Are there many posible configurations? I don't have that information at the moment because I don't have direct access to the api gateway configuration. Should I ask the provider or is it deducible?

Comment: Yes there are many possible configurations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html. You should ask the provider for more information